# How to force LLM to output a variable list of items (such as strings)?

Tags: llm, prompt-design

I want the output of an LLM to be a list of strings, that I can reliably parse to a Python list of strings.

What prompt or completion generation framework should I use?

Comment: Why -1? Is this off-topic for the genai stackexchange?